# How to formatted output a graph of an equation using python?

Tags: python, loops

I am a beginner so I don't think I need to use anything complicated.
Basically I have to `print y=x^+3` for the range`x=0` to `x=4` using formatted output and I don't know how.

From what I have learned so far, I'm supposed to use formatted output, looping and variable width output to do this.

Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure you have to plot it, and not print it? Also have you learned Tkinter or any python GUI?

Comment: yeah i think i have to print it, but I haven't learned Tkinter or python GUI,is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: I mean print as in the python command. That prints it out onto the screen

Comment: that's what i meant, how to do it

Comment: Are you sure you have to graph?

Comment: Are you using ipython notebook?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the module matplotlib, it was made to give plotting visuals in python. I hope this helps a little.

Comment: thanks, but may be i just have to print the line, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Print line in console, not that I know of. But using matplotlib you can create visual files. Otherwise I'm not sure, sorry

Answer (score 0):

> may be i just have to print the line, is there any way to do this?

Here is an example:

```
for x in range(3, 7):
    y = x + 2
    print "With x equal to {},  y = {}".format(x, y)

--output:--
With x equal to 3,  y = 5
With x equal to 4,  y = 6
With x equal to 5,  y = 7
With x equal to 6,  y = 8
```

The arguments to the format() method are substituted in place of the '{}' sequences, in order, from left to right.  You can also specify the order yourself:

```
                                       +---+-----------------+
for x in range(3, 7):                  |   |                 |
    y = x + 2                          V   V                 |
    print "Here are some numbers: {0} {1} {1} {0}".format(x, y)
                                   ^           ^          | 
                                   |           |          |  
                                   +-----------+----------+  
--output:--
Here are some numbers: 3 5 5 3
Here are some numbers: 4 6 6 4
Here are some numbers: 5 7 7 5
Here are some numbers: 6 8 8 6
```

See more examples here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples